# How to combine inputs and spans in form-horizontal form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to combine some spans and some inputs in form-horizontal.

Simple input code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bob: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type='text' data-buttonText="bob" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If I will do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bob: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will get this result:

[image]

So, label text and span text are not in one line. I want to put them on one line. Span's text must be opposite to the label's text. How I can do this using bts methods?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/gagiwu/1/edit It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` tag inside `form-group` has specific height given by framework. But when you omit the tag and fills in just the text, then it has no prescribed `padding`, `margin` and/or `height`. So in order to get it aligned you need to put an extra `div` inside `col-*` class and give it `padding-top`

e.g.

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <div style="padding-top: 6px;">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Padding helped me, but it was too obvious solution :) thought it is possible to achieve what I want without magic numbers :'(

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer dude :)
You can achieve this without `padding`, if you give the `inner-div` a specific height in `css`. Because input works fine only because they have specific `height` and `padding` in `css`.
@sharikovvladislav

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this. no need to use extra div.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bob: </label><span>Some text</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9et1m6n/